# Passing ContentStringFormat into Datatemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, string-formatting, datatemplate

My goal is to pass formated strings into datatemplate:

```
<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource WorkingLabelTemplate}"    Content="123"
                ContentStringFormat="Number is {0}" Grid.Row="0"/>

<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource NotWorkingLabelTemplate}" Content="123"
                ContentStringFormat="Number is {0}" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

**First approach:**

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="WorkingLabelTemplate">
    <Label Content="{Binding}"
            ContentStringFormat="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
            Path=ContentStringFormat, Converter={StaticResource TestConverter}}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

**Second approach:**

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="NotWorkingLabelTemplate">
    <Label Content="{Binding}" 
            ContentStringFormat="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContentControl},
            Path=ContentStringFormat, Converter={StaticResource TestConverter}}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

For both approaches TestConverter says, that binding is working correctly:

> TestConverter: 'Number is {0}' of type 'System.String' to 'System.String', parameter ''
>   TestConverter: 'Number is {0}' of type 'System.String' to 'System.String', parameter ''

But second approach does not work:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ic763.png)

**Question:**
Why second approach does not work, while binding result is the same?

Comment: Both are not working for me!

Comment: Dipen, whats your problem?

Comment: Both of them display 123.

Comment: Please, attach you sample project, or take my: https://www.dropbox.com/s/l4mwj1at00b84r2/StringFormatTestProject.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**

I used your project and found same thing happening on all .Net frameworks installed on my machine. So I dug more dipper to find out what is going on, and I have reached at conclusion that it is just a **timing issue**, `ContentStringFormat` property for your working template is being evaluated bit earlier (before label was drawn) than it is for your not working template.

**Solution**

Just to solve your issue change your constructor code from:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    this.DataContext = this;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

To:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;
}
```

*Keep on reading if you want to read about some thing really interesting!*

**Why do I believe it is a timing issue?**

I set diagnosis properties on both templates `diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High` and found following log.

*Working template*
[image]

*Not working template*
[image]

If you look both pictures closely, you'll see there is a timing difference between time taken for evaluating `ContentStringFormat` property.

**Another Proof**

I made another change in your project which proved my belief to be true. If you run code below, it is similar to your project but with two additional buttons; one to change data and another to change string format. When you run the program and **change string format, content is not re-render with new string format** but when you change the data it self, it reevaluated string format and re-renders the control!

*MainWindow.xaml*

```
<Window x:Class="StringFormatTestProject.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StringFormatTestProject"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:diag="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:TestConverter x:Key="TestConverter"/>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="WorkingLabelTemplate">
            <Label Content="{Binding diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"
                   ContentStringFormat="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                                                 Path=ContentStringFormat, Converter={StaticResource TestConverter}, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="NotWorkingLabelTemplate">
            <Label Content="{Binding}"
                   ContentStringFormat="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContentControl},
                                                 Path=ContentStringFormat, Converter={StaticResource TestConverter}}">
            </Label>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


        <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource NotWorkingLabelTemplate}" Content="{Binding SomeDatatInVM}"
                        ContentStringFormat="{Binding FormatStringInVM}" Grid.Row="0"/>

        <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource WorkingLabelTemplate}"    Content="{Binding SomeDatatInVM}"
                        ContentStringFormat="{Binding FormatStringInVM}" Grid.Row="1"/>

        <Grid Grid.Row="2">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Button Click="Button_Click" Grid.Column="0">Change Data</Button>
            <Button Click="Button_Click_1" Grid.Column="2">Change Format String</Button>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

*MainWindow.xaml.cs*

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string formatStringInVM = "Peer: {0}";
    public string FormatStringInVM
    {
        get { return formatStringInVM; }
        set
        {
            formatStringInVM = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(FormatStringInVM)));
        }
    }

    private int someDatatInVM = 123;
    public int SomeDatatInVM
    {
        get { return someDatatInVM; }
        set
        {
            someDatatInVM = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SomeDatatInVM)));
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {    
        this.DataContext = this;

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SomeDatatInVM++;
    }

    private static int i = 1;
    private void Button_Click_1(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FormatStringInVM = "Peer-" + i.ToString() + ": {0}";
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for "diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High"! I tottaly forgot about this :( About solution: it does not work on my side. And as i understand, .net version & cpu become important: v4 full:461808, i5-4460@3.2GHz

Comment: That is strange, I'll post a link to my shared project sometime today.